# Retrieve the value of certain tag from within the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, aws-cli

I am trying to retrieve the value of certain tag (say environment) of a instance with specific name.

Is it somehow possible to do this using describe-tags or any script? Unfortunately I cannot use describe-instance.

Thanks in advance.

To make it clear if EC2 instance name is ABC-app-dev and there is user tag 'environment' with value 'dev', I want to get the value of environment i.e. dev from within the instance itself.

Comment: When you say "if EC2 instance name is ABC-app-dev", are you referring to a Tag with `Key=Name` and `Value=ABC-app-dev` being attached to the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty here is that the `Name` of an instance is actually just a tag itself. Thus, you have to search for a tag associate with an instance by specifying the Name tag, then look at the other tags.

The [`describe-tags` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-tags.html) can list the Name tags:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-type,Values=instance" "Name=key,Values=Name"
```

You would then need to find the specific instance with the matching name:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-type,Values=instance" "Name=key,Values=Name" "Name=value,Values=MY-NAME"
```

However, all this returns is the tag you have already specified, rather than the other tags for the instance.

You really need a 2-step process that first finds the Instance ID, then retrieves the tags for that instance:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=`aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-type,Values=instance" "Name=key,Values=Name" "Name=value,Values=MY-NAME" --query Tags[].ResourceId --output text`" "Name=key,Values=MY-TAG-NAME" --query Tags[].Value --output text
```